# Skip general rule enter/exit listener method in favor of more specific one? (ANTLR4)

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I have generated a grammar in ANTLR4. A sample excerpt is shown below:

```
list    : defunExpr            # defun
        : lambdaExpr           # lambda
        : condExpr             # cond

        ...

        : items                # other
        ;
```

The rules are listed in order of priority and are called as appropriate when testing the grammar. All higher priority rules of #defun, #lambda, #cond, etc. would also match items (#other) if they did not match higher up (expected behavior of placing higher-priority rules before lower).

I then implemented a simple listener-based application in Java, which simply formats the parsed code and prints it back out the the console. I have overridden the appropriate enter/exit methods for #defun, #lambda, #cond, etc. I would like to implement a generalized catch-all for items which do not match the more specific rule. However, when I implement enter/exit methods for #other, it executes for every matched rule further up the priority as well, effectively outputting formatted code twice for rules such as #defun, #lambda, #cond, etc.

Is there some way to achieve this behavior? I have a handful of specific rules I want to implement, and then have a general case catch the others. The grammar parses properly (test rig shows expected behavior over numerous test cases), but the catch-all method (enterOther) seems to act upon the specific rules as well.

EDIT: Wow, after all this time and posting this question, I now actually believe it is a grammar error. I will leave the question open until I verify, however.

Comment: I don't really know what you're trying to do, but are you sure visitors wouldn't be a better choice for processing expression trees?

Comment: "All higher priority rules [...] would also match `items` if they did not match higher up". Looks like grammar ambiguity to me.

Comment: `enterOther` is definitely not a catch-all rule by the syntax shown above. Can you add a complete example which reproduces the behavior you are seeing?

Comment: Are you sure that 'items' isn't the only 'list' subrule that is  matched and there for 'enterOther' is always called?

Comment: Thanks for the interest, guys. I'm not evaluating anything, just echoing parsed input, so listeners work fine. Grammar was actually fine, non-ambiguous. The catch-all rule (it was catch-all, despite not showing enough of my grammar here) worked fine. My problem (embarrassingly), was that while I wanted to write enter/exit #other methods, I was actually writing enter/exit Expr methods the whole time, which was why all specific rules we triggered as well (since they are Exprs). Embarrassing, but lesson learned. Thanks for the ideas and taking the time. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the interest, guys. I'm not evaluating anything, just echoing parsed input, so listeners work fine. Grammar was actually fine, non-ambiguous. The catch-all rule (it was catch-all, despite not showing enough of my grammar here) worked fine. My problem (embarrassingly), was that while I wanted to write enter/exit #other methods, I was actually writing enter/exit Expr methods the whole time, which was why all specific rules we triggered as well (since they are Exprs). Embarrassing, but lesson learned. Thanks for the ideas and taking the time. Cheers!